# Parsing this XML feed using PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I have an xml feed at this [url](http://www.supashare.net/test.xml)

Now im trying parse the content, particularly the content in `<REDIRECT></REDIRECT>` tags.
I use the following code to try and parse the content but it isnt working and im not sure what im doing wrong.

```
$xml_file = $ADurl;

$xml_headline_key = "*XML*RESULTS*LISTING*REDIRECT";
$xml_description_key = "*XML*RESULTS*LISTING*REDIRECT";

$story_array = array();

$counter = 0;
class xml_story{
    var $headline, $description;
}

function startTag($parser, $data){
    global $current_tag;
    $current_tag .= "*$data";
}

function endTag($parser, $data){
    global $current_tag;
    $tag_key = strrpos($current_tag, '*');
    $current_tag = substr($current_tag, 0, $tag_key);
}

function contents($parser, $data){
    global $current_tag, $xml_headline_key, $xml_description_key, $counter, $story_array;
    switch($current_tag){
        case $xml_headline_key:
            $story_array[$counter] = new xml_story();
            $story_array[$counter]->headline = $data;
            break;
        case $xml_description_key:
            $story_array[$counter]->description = $data;
            $counter++;
            break;
    }
}

$xml_parser = xml_parser_create();

xml_set_element_handler($xml_parser, "startTag", "endTag");

xml_set_character_data_handler($xml_parser, "contents");

$fp = fopen($xml_file, "r") or die("Could not open file");

$data = fread($fp, 1024) or die("Could not read file");

if(!(xml_parse($xml_parser, $data, feof($fp)))){
    die("Error on line " . xml_get_current_line_number($xml_parser));
}

xml_parser_free($xml_parser);

fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't use [simplexml](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)?

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.supashare.net/test.xml'); 
$result = $xml->xpath('/XML/RESULTS/LISTING/REDIRECT');
echo $result[0];
```

Comment: Turn on errors see what happens. Your server may not have allow_url_fopen enabled, in which case you would have to edit your php.ini (if possible) to enable it.

Comment: if simplexml_load_file won't work then replace it with this....

$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($url));  

where $url is the url you want

Comment: (and if "file_get_contents" won't retrieve the remote file, then you'll have to check your INI file....) -- But regardless you should be able to get the remote contents and shove into a string - and then into simplexml_load_string...

Comment: file_get_contents($url) works fine by itself but it doesnt load within simplexml

Comment: if file_get_contents works, then you just pass that string to simplexml_load_string() instead, and it will work.  Not sure why one would work and not the other though, im pretty sure they both use the fopen wrapper.

Comment: When using file_get_contents(), the whole xml file isnt read, only a few bits of text within the file is. I think that is why file_get_contents() works but not within simplexml

Answer (score 2):

```
$xml = stream_get_contents($fp);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
echo $xml->RESULTS->LISTING->REDIRECT;
```

Comment: Well the problem is that it cant parse remote xml files.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you have the XML file locally on your server? If so, change the URL to that filename and it will work.

Comment: Nope, the xml file is on another server on another server.

Comment: EDIT: I have changed it to use the $fp you defined in your code. Will this work?

Answer (score 1):

```
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->load('http://www.supashare.net/test.xml');
$q = new DomXPath($doc);
echo $q->query('//REDIRECT')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Comment: I remember you from sitepoint, you were a guy whose posts i loved to read.  Can you tell me why you chose domdocument over simplexml?

Comment: Hmm.. I think your confusing me with something else :S
As to your answer.. its not working with remote XML files either

Comment: They use the same underlying parse (libxml), so it's just syntax. Personally I like DOM better because it's a standard api. It's just a preference.